# How to access SCNSceneRendererDelegate methods when using SceneKit with SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, scenekit

I am using SceneKit with SwiftUI by following solution provided by Mehdi to this question:

[SwiftUI - how to add a Scenekit Scene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56743724/swiftui-how-to-add-a-scenekit-scene)

Normally, when one creates a SceneKit project, implementing the renderer methods is as easy as just adding the the following extension in the GameViewController file and implementing each of the renderer methods:

```
extension GameViewController: SCNSceneRendererDelegate {
  // 2
  func renderer(renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: NSTimeInterval) {
    // 3
    doWhatever()
  }
}
```

But when using SwiftUI, we use a struct instead of a class (see above linked question), so we cannot simply add the extension, because Xcode complains:

```
Non-class type 'ScenekitView" cannot conform to class protocol 'NSObjectProtocol'
Non-class type 'ScenekitView' cannot conform to class protocol 'SCNSceneRendererDelegate'
```

What is the solution to this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the solution in this answer:

[SwiftUI – Passing data from SwiftUIView to SceneKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60582392/swiftui-passing-data-from-swiftuiview-to-scenekit)

At the lower half of Andy's question he describes how to use a coordinator to implement the delegate methods. Reproducing here for convenience:

```
struct ScenekitView: NSViewRepresentable {

    @Binding var showStats: Bool
    let sceneView = SCNView(frame: .zero)
    let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/ship.scn")!

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    final class Coordinator: NSObject, SCNSceneRendererDelegate {
        var control: ScenekitView

        init(_ control: ScenekitView) {
            self.control = control
        }

        func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer,
               updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) {

            control.sceneView.showsStatistics = control.showStats

            for i in 0...255 {
                control.sceneView.backgroundColor = NSColor(
                                  red: CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(i))),
                                green: CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(i))),
                                 blue: CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(i))),
                                alpha: 1.0)
            }
        }
    }

    func scnScene(stat: Bool, context: Context) -> SCNView {
        sceneView.scene = scene
        sceneView.showsStatistics = stat
        sceneView.delegate = context.coordinator
        return sceneView
    }

    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> SCNView {
        scnScene(stat: true, context: context)
    }

    func updateNSView(_ uiView: SCNView, context: Context) { }
}
```

Comment: Your use of the coordinator was exactly, what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you are brave and don't want to import anything but SwiftUI:

1. Create helper class `SceneRendererDelegate` and implement anything you want:

   ```
   import SceneKit

   // the hackiest hack ever. And the stupidest one!
   // For handling touches in SceneView we need SCNSceneRenderer,
   // but SwiftUI's SceneView does not provide it.
   class SceneRendererDelegate: NSObject, SCNSceneRendererDelegate {
     var renderer: SCNSceneRenderer?
     var onEachFrame: (() -> ())? = nil

     func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) {
       if self.renderer == nil {
         self.renderer = renderer
         let type = type(of: renderer)

         print("We got SceneRenderer: \(type)")
       }

       onEachFrame?()
     }
   }
   ```
2. Add it to your `GameView`:

   ```
   import SwiftUI
   import SceneKit

   struct GameView: View {
    var sceneRendererDelegate = SceneRendererDelegate()

    var body: some View {
      ZStack {
        SceneView(
          scene: yourScene,
          options: [
            .temporalAntialiasingEnabled
          ],
          delegate: sceneRendererDelegate)
      }
      .onDisappear {
        // Make sure your code disabled in background
        sceneRendererDelegate.onEachFrame = nil
      }
      .onAppear {
        sceneRendererDelegate.onEachFrame = { 
          // Your code on every frame
        }
      }
    }
   }
   ```

You can check and run live demos from my old [SwiftUI-Games](https://github.com/damikdk/SwiftUI-Games)

Comment: Sadly downloaded SwiftUI-Games and ran it and nothing works under iOS16, crashes.

Comment: @user3069232 you can write issue [there](https://github.com/damikdk/SwiftUI-Games/issues). If you tried to run it on simulator, I just fixed the crash